# Convering a Decimal Fractional Number to Hexadecimal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Let's say I have a decimal number like 5.8463
I know how to convert the integer part to Hex, by either putting it into binary first then grouping it into 4 bits, then to hex. Or using a divide method.
However, I don't understand how to get the decimal into hex.

I was told that I have to multiply the Decimal by 16 several times.
But the thing is, my course does not permit the use of calculators, so how does one

do `0.8463 * 16` In ones head?

I Guess my mental math is lacking, or its simply the inexperience in doing these kinds of multiplication problems.
Any help on that, and further how to attempt the question would be much appreciated.

Comment: Who said that you have to do it in your head ? It's a written exam, right ?

Comment: Yeah, but woudn't it take forever to have to write it out, just to do one question, worth a single mark. Repeat that for several other questions, and I'm spending most of my time multiplying decimals (if you get what I'm saying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the binary expansion easily, no multiplying by 16 required. One way to do it: repeatedly double the number you're expanding, write down the integer part and subtract it away, and repeat. For $0.8463$ this gives:

$$\begin{array}[ccc]\relax
0.8463&1.6926&1\\
0.6926&1.3852&1\\
0.3852&0.7704&0\\
0.7704&1.5408&1\\
0.5408&1.0816&1\\
0.0816&0.1632&0\\
0.1632&0.3264&0\\
0.3264&0.6528&0\\
\cdots\\
\end{array}
$$
So the binary expansion of $0.8463$ is $0.\underbrace{1101}_d\underbrace{1000}_8\ldots$, or $0.d8\ldots$ in hex.

Comment: So you double 0.8 to get 1.6, but how are you getting the rest of the decimals? Also the next line, double 0.6, gets you 1.3...? not 1.2...?

Comment: You double 0.8463 to get 1.6926; throw away the 1 to get the 0.6926 which starts the next line.

Comment: It''s just the fact that I can't use a calculator, so I'd have to write out the number twice and do the math on paper, which would take a while.

Comment: Thanks anyway, this is definitely easier than multiplying by 16